# Button to refresh page doesn't work if I have get parameters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this button in my website

```
<input class="large button gray input" id="refrescar" type="submit" value="Confirmar"/>
```

That I use to refresh the site manually like this:

```
    $('#refrescar').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

It works on almost all the pages of my web except on those that have get parameters like this:

```
     http://mywebsite.com/page.php?id=2
```

When I click the button in that page it will go to

```
     http://mywebsite.com/page.php
```

instead.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `type="submit"`, use `type="button"`, because I think currently the button submits the form instead of reloading it.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I made this mistake... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to instead

```
<input class="large button gray input" id="refrescar" type="submit" value="Confirmar"/>
```

to

```
<input class="large button gray input" id="refrescar" type="button" value="Confirmar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
location.reload(location.href);
```

that will pass the url and query string to the reload function